# How to Remove ScanSnap Tile from Devices and drives

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'd like to remove the tile shown below, without uninstalling the program. It doesn't seem like it is an actual folder that can be removed - maybe it is a registry key?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys you're looking for are in the following locations:

**For Explorer**

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace`

**For SaveAs and Open File dialougs**

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace`

**Here are the following keys to expect**

`{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}` (Music folder)

`{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}` (Downloads folder)

`{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}` (Pictures folder)

`{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}` (Videos folder)

`{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}` (Documents folder)

`{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}` (Desktop folder)

To remove the folders simple delete the key. (Deleting all the above mentioned keys will effectively remove the "Folders" selection all together.

Using this guide, and process of elimination should help you remove the bugger. Additionally you can add items here aswell =) I added this one `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}` which is the control panel.

Goodluck in your ventures! Feel free to voteup/accept answer if this response is acceptable.

**Note:** If you get the following error message, let me know.

`Cannot delete {☺☻♀♂♪♫☼►-♦♣♠•-♠♠♣♣-♥♥♦♦-←↑↓↨→↕→♫←↕‼¶§}: Error while deleting key.`

**Source 1:** http://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-recycle-bin-run-search-and-many-other-useful-shortcuts-in-my-computer/

**Source 2:** http://www.askvg.com/tips-tweak-and-customize-windows-8-1-explorer-this-pc/

Answer (score 1):

The ScanSnap folder can be removed by unregistering its `.dll` file. No log off/restart required.

1. Open an command prompt with administrator rights.
2. Type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   `regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files\PFU\ScanSnap\SSFolder\SSFolder.dll"`

Upon unregistering, the following keys will be deleted:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\SSFolder.DLL
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{3DB87E3A-2490-49DA-BA7C-5931849992CE}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{591C1901-C0DA-4776-8450-F9806F6E9687}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{D1B23810-58C6-4B22-A01B-AF521433D434}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SSFolder.ShellFolderImpl
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SSFolder.ShellFolderImpl.1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{8D4FB007-2F3F-4C51-BD10-D39D5445C59B}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{591C1901-C0DA-4776-8450-F9806F6E9687}
```

Comment: I had to do this step as well as then remove the key located in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace

Comment: @Kirk You don't need to manually delete any registry key items. The command I posted will take care of everything for you and should work even if the related keys change in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows 10 (64-bit) host, open a command prompt with administrator rights and then invoke this command line:

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\PFU\ScanSnap\SSFolder\x64\SSFolder.DLL"
```

*NB: This answer was derived from the answer provided by @and31415:*
https://superuser.com/a/703657/484629